# sed: удаление строк со всеми вхождениями кроме первой

Tags: sed

Требуется оставить строку только с первым вхождением, все остальные строки удалить.
Казалось бы, `sed 's/pattern//2g'` должно это сделать, однако не работает (sed --version sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2).
Пример:

```
cat text
123
123
123
234
234
345
```

требуется получить возврат:

```
123
234
234
345
```

Однако, при `cat text | sed 's/123//2g'` получаю возврат исходного файла без изменений.
А при только `g` удаляются все и почему-то остаются пустые строки:

```
cat text | sed 's/123//g'



234
234
345
```

Как правильно реализовать с помощью sed ? Спасибо.

Comment: возможно потребуется удалить все дубликаты и тогда лучше использовать `uniq`

Comment: я упростил задачу в вопросе, на самом деле исходный текст состоит из нескольких полей, где дубликаты лишь частично совпадают паттернами, потому простое решение типа `sort - u` или `uniq` или аналоги не сработают

Comment: В этом как раз поможет `sort` где `-t` указать разделите полей, `-k` выбрать столбцы по которым выполняем сверку и ключ -u вывести уникальные записи по этим полям. К примеру для строку `123,321,222` нам нужно удалить дубли второго столбца, то команда будет выглядеть так `...| sort -t"," -k'2,2' -u`, попробуйте может это как раз то что нужно, в ключе -k указывается диапазон столбцов для проверки.

Comment: да, это работает, спасибо! Но все же если кто знает ответ на sed, отпишитесь, бывают и такие ситуации.

Comment: `sed '$!N; /^\(123\)\n\1$/!P; D'` - нашел на просторах, возможно поможет.

Answer (score 2):

Решение с `awk` подойдёт?

```sh
$ awk '/123/ { if (!x) { print; x = 1; } }; !/123/ { print; }' file.txt
```